# Tick sign is not centered on single badge page

Tags: bug, design, badges

On the user's [badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/147/vox-populi?userid=339911) tick sign is not centered relative to the badge:

> [image: user page]

On the [all badges list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) it looks centered:

> [image: all badges]

Comment: There's an unnecessary `vertical-align: top;` on the misaligned one.

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Won't Yes. SE contains too much bugs!