# Alignment for the "A" icon in the hot questions list

Tags: feature-request, design, android-app

Hot questions page for the Android app contains a list. Each item in the list contains "A" icon with the following number of answers:

> [image]

You can see that if answers count is 10+ then "A" is shifted to the left for giving enough space for numbers.

My request is to fix "A" x-position, for example by swaping numbers and icons. In this case page will looks more nicely.

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Won't nice to see you ... [again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287196/tick-sign-is-not-centered#comment931934_287196).

Comment: I do need to add more fun to that pic.  Sorry, I'll do better next time.

Comment: No ... you @Won't ... user1228